error on Maven central when building gradle.build.kts
Hello I am trying to build a simple app using gradle/kotlin.
I get the following error
    ScriptCompilationException(scriptCompilationErrors=[ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: tools, location=/Users/mb/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-10380752879717133611.tmp/build.gradle.kts (1:5)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline fun RepositoryHandler.mavenCentral(vararg args: Pair<String, Any?>): MavenArtifactRepository defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl, location=/Users/mb/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-10380752879717133611.tmp/build.gradle.kts (6:5))])

my buld.gradle.kts should be simple:
jdk.tools.jlink.resources.plugins {
    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":jvm-shared"))

    testImplementation(libs.junit.jupiter)
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.myApp.App")
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.register<Wrapper>("wrapper") {
    gradleVersion = "8.7"
}

tasks.register("prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel"){}

can you please point me where things went wrong so I can resolve this issue?
